# Laravel cursor usage dilemma

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

`get` works while `cursor` returns blank

```
$excep[] = DB::table('table')->where('user_id', $user)->select('data')->get();
return $excep;  // returns some sql data
```

But with `cursor`:

```
$excep[] = DB::table('table')->where('user_id', $user)->select('data')->cursor();
return $excep; // returns [{}]
```

Information isn't enough to understand: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#chunking-results

Comment: cursor works with Eloquent, not with Query Builder

Comment: It doesn't work. `$excep[] = Userdata::where('user_id', $user)->cursor();`

Answer (score 0):

`cursor` only can be used on iterations, if you need all data at once, you must use `get`.

```php
// All users will be loaded on memory first on collection and then, iterate.
// You can return all users as return UserModel::get();

foreach (UserModel::get() as $user) {
    $this->sendWellcomeMail($user);
}
```

```php
// Only one user on memory on each iteration.
// You can NOT return all users with return UserModel::cursor();

foreach (UserModel::cursor() as $user) {
    $this->sendWellcomeMail($user);
}
```